# Can Closetmaid wall clips be reinstalled after painting?

Tags: shelving, wire

I have Closetmaid wire shelving in my laundry room. I want to remove these so I can paint the walls.  Can I re-use the clips to re-install the shelves once I finish painting?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This should be directed to the manufacturer as it is a product specific question.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo The fact that it's product-specific does not mean it's off-topic here. We routinely answer product-specific questions (and even ask for model numbers in many cases!) about all kinds of products.

Comment: Ahem: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Closetmaid makes a lot of *clips*. Can you provide a photo or link to the actual clip you are talking about. Also do you mean remove the shelf from the clip or the clip from the wall?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the clips used for the install. I already am sure the large clips for the forward edge of the shelves have the wall inserts as part of the clip, and when you pull the pin and remove the clip the drywall will never be the same. With care, you can reuse the clip. The clips for the back wall, if they have the inserts as part of the clip, the situation will be the same as the larger clips, the drywall will not take well to having the insert withdrawn. If the back wall clips have separate drywall inserts and can stay in thew wall while removing the support clips, have at it and paint away.